# undefined method authenticated? (Sinatra + Warden)

Tags: ruby, sinatra, warden

When I add the `authorize!` method in controller, I get an error

```
NoMethodError - undefined method authenticated? for nil:NilClass
```

My controller

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra_warden'
require 'warden'

class LoginManager < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::Warden
end

use Rack::Session::Pool

get '/dashboard' do
  authorize!('/login')
  erb :dashboard
end
```

sinatra_warden 0.3.2

warden 1.2.6

where did I go wrong?

Comment: Please share all code that related to the problem, I mean the controller too.

Comment: added to question body

Comment: the authorize method outside of the LoginManager, that's a problem.

Comment: now i have error `Couldn't find Post with id=admin:'

Comment: What an another question. Keep in mind StackOverflow is not your debuggin tool.

Comment: class `LoginManager` move before and after action `get /:id`, but nothing changes

Comment: Move `class` before or after shouldn't relfect to something.